# Kotlin coroutine unit test fails with "Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize"

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

While running unit test for kotlin suspend method which uses `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` the test method fails with below exception:

My coroutine lib versions are **kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1** and **kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1**

Example:

```
suspend fun methodToTest() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
           doSomethingOnMainThread()
                val data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    doSomethingOnIOThread()
                }
        }
    }
```

Also, when I remove the `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` it works fine.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize. For tests Dispatchers.setMain from kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used

at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.missing(MainDispatchers.kt:79)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MissingMainCoroutineDispatcher.isDispatchNeeded(MainDispatchers.kt:54)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedKt.resumeCancellable(Dispatched.kt:373)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:25)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:152)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't have access to Dispatchers.Main in unit testing

See https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/

`Dispatchers.Main Delegation` part explains in detail what you need to do.

Comment: It needs mocking of main Thread using Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate). Also need to add kotlinx-coroutines-test as dependency

Comment: Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined) also works

Answer (score 112):

**UPDATED 2023**

Add the following dependency on your gradle. [Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test)

```
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"
```

Add the following Custom TestRule as a utility for your tests

```
// Reusable JUnit4 TestRule to override the Main dispatcher
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
class MainDispatcherRule(
    private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {
    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

In your test do the following

```
@get:Rule
val mainDispatcherRule = MainDispatcherRule()
```

**OLD ANSWER**

When running tests e.g for ViewModel that launch coroutines you are most likely to fall into the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had
> failed to initialize. For tests, Dispatchers.setMain from
> kotlinx-coroutines-test module can be used

The reason behind this is the lack of `Looper.getMainLooper()` on the testing environment which is present on a real application. To fix this you need to swap the Main dispatcher with `TestCoroutineDispatcher`

Make sure you have a coroutine-test dependency on your Gradle file

> "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutine_version"

**SOLUTION 1** - Not scalable

Define the following on your test class -> Annotate your class with `@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi`

```
val dispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()

@Before
fun setup() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}
```

Note: You can also pass `Dispatchers.Main` as constructor dependency for your repositories as `CoroutineDispatcher` in case you have one. It is recommended not to hardcode your dispatchers on repositories/viewmodels etc [WATCH-THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMb0Fs8rCRs&feature=youtu.be&t=808) PLEASEEEEEEEE

Why not scalable: You will need to copy and paste the same code on each test class

**SOLUTION 2** - Scalable [Use This - *It is used by Google*]

In this solution, you create the custom rule. Add a utility class on your test package

```kotlin
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    class MainCoroutineRule(
        private val dispatcher: TestCoroutineDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher()
    ) : TestWatcher(), TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope(dispatcher) {
        override fun starting(description: Description?) {
            super.starting(description)
            Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
        }
    
        override fun finished(description: Description?) {
            super.finished(description)
            cleanupTestCoroutines()
            Dispatchers.resetMain()
        }
    }
```

If you want explanations on the utility class above, refer to this [CODE-LAB](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-testing-survey/#3)

On your test class just add this the following lines and you will be good to go:

```kotlin
    @get:Rule
    val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()
```

I think you can see why this is scalable if you have a lot of test classes.

**SOLUTION 3** [I hope you don't reach here]

You can also use `Dispatchers.Unconfined` [LINK](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html)

> A coroutine dispatcher that is not confined to any specific thread. It executes the initial continuation of a coroutine in the current call-frame and lets the coroutine resume in whatever thread that is used by the corresponding suspending function, without mandating any specific threading policy. Nested coroutines launched in this dispatcher form an event-loop to avoid stack overflows.

You can add it as follows

```kotlin
    @Before
    fun setup() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
    }
    
    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
```

Comment: Nice answer, given the context of unit testing, do you think solution 3 is a simple and good enough approach when compared to solution 2?

Comment: `TestCoroutineDispatcher` is deprecated, to use `StandardTestDispatcher` or `UnconfinedTestDispatcher`

Comment: Followed example exactly. I am still getting the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: Also doesn't work for me. Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Same, not works for me too

Answer (score 15):

now you can add this to your test :

```
Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
```

or other dispatcher.. it's **experimental** but it **works**!

Comment: work for me. I'm developing a KMM project, this sol works for the commonTest.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I had set the main coroutines dispatcher for unit testing and still saw some errors of that from time to time.

I've added to the build.gradle as in [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support#TOC-Method-...-not-mocked.-):

```
android {
  // ...
  testOptions { 
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
  }
}
```

and I don't see that error anymore.

Answer (score 5):

This is thrown because Dispatcher.Main is missing. It is Android based and therefore cannot be used for unit tests. The solution lies in the documentation by the Coroutines team. Below is an example that solved my problem and is included in the documentation.

```
class SomeTest {
    
    private val mainThreadSurrogate = newSingleThreadContext("UI thread")

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        Dispatchers.resetMain() // reset main dispatcher to the original Main dispatcher
        mainThreadSurrogate.close()
    }
    
    @Test
    fun testSomeUI() = runBlocking {
        launch(Dispatchers.Main) {  // Will be launched in the mainThreadSurrogate dispatcher
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

What you should note is `newSingleThreadContext("UI Thread")` and `Dispatchers.setMain(mainThreadSurrogate)` which is called before any tests in order to create a Main Dispatcher.

Comment: Adding a reference to the documentation could be helpful for future references.
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and I found the solution here [kotlinx.coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/932)
the solution is to use Coroutines version 1.1.0 I try it and Now it work perfectly

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

`TestCoroutineDispatcher` is now deprecated. the suggested way is to use `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` like below

```
    // Reusable JUnit4 TestRule to override the Main dispatcher
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainDispatcherRule(
    private val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher(),
) : TestWatcher() {
    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

refer [Setting the Main dispatcher](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#setting-main-dispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

For **JUnit 5 tests** you can use the following solution:

Step 1: Create JUnit 5 extension

```
/**
 * Sets the main coroutine dispatcher to a test dispatcher for unit testing.
 * A test dispatcher provides control over the execution of coroutines.
 */
internal class MainCoroutineExtension : BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

    override fun beforeEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(dispatcher)
    }

    override fun afterEach(context: ExtensionContext) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }

    companion object {
        val dispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
    }
}
```

Step 2: Create an annotation for the extension

```
/**
 * Sets the main coroutine dispatcher for JUnit 5 tests.
 * You should need this annotation mainly for ViewModel tests.
 */
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@ExtendWith(MainCoroutineExtension::class)
annotation class MainCoroutine
```

Step 3: Use the extension on ViewModel test classes

```
@MainCoroutine
internal class HomeViewModelTest { ...
```

Note: Instead of creating annotation you can use directly the extension. I find the annotation solution cleaner.

```
@ExtendWith(MainCoroutineExtension::class)
internal class HomeViewModelTest { ...
```